# Работаем на вынос

Tags: наречия

Недавно при входе в одно заведение при выходе заметил: работаем на вынос.

В данном случае ведь слово "навынос" является наречием и пишется слитно? Ведь можно же поставить вопрос "На что?"

Comment: Если "можно же поставить вопрос "На что?", тогда надо задать вопрос  ЧЕГО? На вынос ЧЕГО? Бумаги, например.

Comment: На вынос блюд, продуктов)

Comment: Ну, да. Из ресторана через черный ход)

Answer (score 3):

Действительно, когда мы видим подобные таблички, то лучше всего зайти на сайт Грамота.ру, чтобы узнать, как там **сейчас пишут** (нормы могут меняться).
Смотрим в словаре: ***навынос***.

Существует **особая тематическая группа наречий,** связанных с глаголами ПОКУПАТЬ, ТОРГОВАТЬ, ПРОДАВАТЬ, и решения по выбору формы письма  для этой группы не очень последовательны, а именно:

КУПИТЬ в складчину, в рассрочку, в кредит, ПРОДАВАТЬ/ТОРГОВАТЬ в разлив, **на развес**, в розницу, но:  ПРОДАВАТЬ  **навынос, вразвес**.

**ТЕОРИЯ**

Эта тема вообще очень сложная, выбор формы письма часто делается **по словарю,** но решение все-таки можно обозначить.

Нужно различать **3 группы слов**: (1) **наречия** со слитным написанием, (2) **наречные выражения** (обстоятельственные существительные) с раздельным написанием, (3) **существительные** с раздельным написанием (когда можно задать **падежный вопрос**).

Если есть пара **"наречие – существительное"**, то проблем нет: надеяться (на что?) – на удачу, идти (как?) наудачу.

А если пары нет, если вопрос обстоятельственный в обоих случаях, а написание в словаре  разное?

Тогда надо **проверять правильность падежа для конкретного глагола**. Дело в том,что наиболее частотные предлоги винительного падежа НА и В обычно имеют значение **направленности** (куда? зачем?),  их надо отличать от вопроса (как?) без направленного значения: перейти (как?) **вброд**, но не (куда?) в брод; взять (как?) **напрокат**, но не (зачем?) на прокат.

Но обстоятельственное значение (как?) для В.п. тоже возможно, и это как раз **тематика некоторых наших глаголов:** купить (как?) в кредит, в рассрочку, торговать (как?) в розницу. Обратим внимание, что здесь в основном используется **предлог В.**

**ОТВЕТ**

Правильно: работаем (как?) **навынос.** Это наречие.  Сравнить: разрешение (на что?) **на вынос**. Это существительное.

Вроде  всё правильно, наречие должно писать слитно.

Но (из словаря) продавать (как?) **на развес**.

Вот и приходится учить: **навынос, вразвес**, но: **на развес.** Всё-таки неясно, чем **вразвес** отличается от **на развес**.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (с учетом материалов из Нацкорпуса).

Итак, ***на вынос*** — 142 примера, ***навынос*** — 60 примеров. Такое разнообразие можно объяснить непоследовательностью решений при выборе формы письма для этого слова: менялись правила, да и пользователи не всегда правильно определяли его статус. Поэтому попробуем привести материал к  современным нормам.

1. Эта падежная форма может быть существительным (раздельное написание): *получить разрешение (на что?) **на вынос**.*
2. Эта форма может быть обстоятельственным существительным в роли определения (раздельное написание): *вещи (куда?) **на вынос, на выброс**.*
3. Эта форма может быть наречием (слитное написание, этот вариант обозначен в словаре): *продавать (как?) навынос (= с выносом), кофе и пицца навынос* и даже *книги могут давать почитать **навынос*** (не путать: *книги **на вынос/на выброс***, то есть чтобы выбросить).

Вот такая непростая задачка, в которой форма написания помогает нам понять **семантику** слова.

Comment: У Ушакова было раздельно, прочем со ссылкой на письменную традицию табличек в заведениях и с пометкой "устар.". В современных словарях - слитно и с пометкой "разг.". Любопытно, как слитность сочетается с разговорностью :).

Comment: Посмотрела в Нацкорпусе, там на вынос - 142 примера, навынос- 60 примеров, причем в разное время применялись оба выражения. У меня такое ощущение, что здесь должно быть две формы, а не одна.

Comment: А где раздельно, нет существительного с предлогом, такое тоже бывает.

Comment: Меня не убеждает административно принятая (вероятно, во имя "цельности" какого-то свода правил) логика  выявления _наречия_, поскольку не просматривается образ действия глагола: торгуют одни, выносят другие. Речь идет о торговле товаром, предназначенном _к выносу_ и рассчитанном _на вынос_ (то же с кофе на вынос), - я так все это воспринимаю и не вижу аналогий с "врозливом", "наотмашью" и пр. "Навынос" приемлемо в нетипичном случае, когда нечто "вынесли и торгуют" им.

Answer (score 1):

***Работаем навынос***

Слитное написание слова *навынос* в вашем примере — единственно верный вариант.

Обратимся к справочнику Розенталя:
https://old-rozental.online/orfografia.php?sid=68#pp68

> 6. Пишутся слитно (в одно слово) наречия, если между предлогом-приставкой и существительным, из которых образовалось наречие, не может быть без изменения смысла вставлено определение (прилагательное, числительное, местоимение) или если к существительному не может быть поставлен падежный вопрос

Из указанных Розенталем условий слитного написания наречий в нашем случае подходят все:

**Без изменения смысла не может быть вставлено определение:**

> 1. Работаем на **ваш** вынос
> 2. Работаем на **второй** вынос
> 3. Работаем на **сегодняшний** вынос

В общем, тут и так всё понятно.

**Без изменения смысла к существительному не может быть поставлен падежный вопрос:**

А вот тут у автора возникло сомнение — вопрос «на что?» ведь поставить вроде можно?

Действительно, вопрос вы поставили, но остался ли смысл неизменным? Ведь нам важно, именно чтобы **смысл не менялся!**

А смысл как раз меняется:
Если глагол *работаем* связать с существительным в винительном падеже (Кого? Что?) с предлогом *на* то смысл такого словосочетания будет *«действовать в пользу кого-чего-нибудь, проявлять какую-нибудь деятельность в чьих-нибудь интересах»*:

> 1. Время работает на нас
> 2. Мы работаем на Михаила

Как видите, без изменения смысла задать к этому слову падёжный вопрос действительно не удаётся.

Таким образом, так как все условия слитного написания наречия удовлетворены, мы его пишем **слитно**!

Ещё хотелось бы добавить, что зачастую применять правила о слитном, дефисном и раздельном написании наречий и наречных выражений затруднительно — написание некоторых слов им едва ли можно объяснить. Поэтому советую чаще пользоваться толковым словарём ( gramota.ru/slovari/dic/ ); а правила, конечно, надо знать, чтобы, так сказать, в полевых условиях не попасть впросак.